# Get Time From manual datePicker According to selected date swift

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, time-format

[image]I have two fields called date and time. I am creating datepicker by using this code

```
var selectedDate : NSDate!
func date_picker2(textField: UITextField)
    {
        var toolbar1:UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, 40))
        var done:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target:self, action: Selector("cancelBtnClicked1:"))
        done.tag  = 203
        var cancel:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("cancelBtnClicked1:"))

        cancel.tag = 202


   var space:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolbar1.items = [cancel,space,done]
    toolbar1.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 23.0/255.0, green: 174.0/255.0, blue: 202.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
    toolbar1.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    txt_Dob.inputAccessoryView = toolbar1
    txt_birthTime.inputAccessoryView = toolbar1

    datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectMake(toolbar1.frame.size.width - 65, 0, 0, 300))
    let currentCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = -80
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate()


    if txt_Dob.isFirstResponder()
    {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
    }
    if txt_birthTime.isFirstResponder()
    {
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        println("selectedDate: \(selectedDate)")
        if selectedDate == NSDate(){
            datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:0)
        }
    }

    datePicker.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    datePicker.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    datePicker.calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    txt_Dob.inputView = datePicker
    txt_birthTime.inputView = datePicker
}

func cancelBtnClicked1(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var btnTag = sender.tag

    if btnTag == 203
    {
        if( txt_Dob.isFirstResponder())
        {
            if sender.tag == 203
            {
                var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                txt_Dob.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)

            }
        }
        else if( txt_birthTime.isFirstResponder())
        {
            if sender.tag == 203
            {
                var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
                txt_birthTime.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
               }
        }
        txt_Dob.resignFirstResponder()
        txt_birthTime.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    else
    {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

now I want that If I am selecting today's datepicker should allow me to take time till now, but if I will select date the day before yesterday, it should allow me to take any time.

I am not getting how to do that. Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just update the maximum date in case of timepicker and match for current date like :

```
dateComponents.hour = 23
dateComponents.minute = 59
dateComponents.second = 59

datePicker.maximumDate = currentCalendar?.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions())

if txt_Dob.isFirstResponder()
{
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
}
if txt_birthTime.isFirstResponder()
{
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
    if selectedDate == NSDate(){
    datePicker.maximumDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow:0)
    }
}
```

You have to update selectedDate when user will select the date from txt_Dob date picker.

```
if( txt_Dob.isFirstResponder())
    {
        if sender.tag == 203
        {
            var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
            txt_Dob.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
            selectedDate = datePicker.date
            txt_birthTime.text = ""
        }
    }
```

Comment: no.. it is not allowing me to select any time. right now I am selecting time in PM. but it is not allowing @ Muhammad Yawar Ali

Comment: I have updated my code as you said.. @Muhammad Yawar Ali

Comment: Are you updating selectedDate variable with date selected from the txt_Dob datepicker ? If you just want to test timepicker comment the if condition for selectedDate code and check.

Comment: Yes. I am updating selectedDate, but it allows me only to take time since now

Comment: selectedDate should be  updating every time you are selecting txt_Dob date along with resetting the txt_BirthTime picker. I have updated my answer check it.

Comment: Check screenshot which I have added. It is taken at 1:20.. but If I am trying to set date at 1:22 it is not allowing.@Muhammad Yawar Ali

Comment: @RiddhiShah check i have editted the answer i guess we forgot an else part of condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106998/discussion-between-muhammad-yawar-ali-and-riddhi-shah).

Comment: Thank you so much..@Muhammad Yawar Ali